# fatal error: blake2.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, hash, crypto++

I am using RaspberryPi and Crypto++6 is the only available version through apt, I can't include the hash function library blake2, and /usr/include/cryptopp/blake2.h doesnt exist, I tried also to install it manually through github, below how I installed it manually, but still doesn't work and blake.h does not exist in include folder too, what can I do ? thank you in advance !

I was using `<crypto++/libname.h>` because I am using a Debian based distribution (stretch), but when I tried `<cryptopp/blake.h>` it works and this is after I installed the library manually, now I got another errors, what should I use crypto++ or cryptopp

```
/tmp/ccTmS4UQ.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::BLAKE2b::BLAKE2b(bool, unsigned int)'
/tmp/ccTmS4UQ.o: In function `CryptoPP::BLAKE2b::~BLAKE2b()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP7BLAKE2bD2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP7BLAKE2bD5Ev]+0x74): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::BLAKE2b'
test.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP7BLAKE2bD2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP7BLAKE2bD5Ev]+0x78): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::BLAKE2b'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And:

```
uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.19.42-v7+ #1219 SMP Tue May 14 21:20:58 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux

ldconfig -p | grep crypto++
libcrypto++.so.6 (libc6,hard-float) => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypto++.so.6
libcrypto++.so (libc6,hard-float) => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypto++.so
```

And a program:

```
#include <crypto++/cryptlib.h>
#include <crypto++/blake2.h>

#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using namespace CryptoPP;
    BLAKE2b hash;   
    std::cout << "Name: " << hash.AlgorithmName() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Digest size: " << hash.DigestSize() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Block size: " << hash.BlockSize() << std::endl;

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Which package did you install? Typically you need the -dev version...

Comment: @jww thank you for your response! I put the installed packages in the Question

Comment: I was always using <crypto++/libname.h> because I am using a debian based distribution (stretch), but when I tried <cryptopp/blake.h> it works and this is after I installed the library manually, now many errors, what should I use crypto++ or cryptopp

Comment: I have installed it manually after I got the problem, but from the beginning when the libraries auto installed via apt, blake2.h not found in /usr/include/cryptopp, (libcrypto++-dev - libcrypto++-doc - libcrypto++-utils - libcrypto++6 - libcrypto++6-dbg )

Comment: I tried what you said, but still doesn't work, I doubt because of the version(the last version I am allowed to install via apt is 5.6.4-7) and the hashes were added at Crypto++ 5.6.4, I don't know if **-7** make the diference or no !, now I am trying to install another version manually through github

Comment: *"still doesn't work"* is not helpful. You need to (1) state what you are using (Master, ZIP, distro library); (2) show your code; (3) show your command line; and (4) show the error. The question is missing most of the critical information. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @jww thank you very much for the support, I have uninstalled libcrypto++, and uninstalled also the manually installed cyptopp with sudo make uninstall, then `sudo git clone https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp`
 `cd cryptopp`
 `make`
 `make test`
 `sudo make install`, and I have changed the program example from importing `<crypto++/blake2.h>` to `<cryptopp/blake2.h>`, imported successfully but many error of reference and etc, the example is always in the Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have uninstalled the package, and reinstall it manually via github
 `sudo git clone https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp`
 `cd cryptopp`
 `sudo make`
 `sudo make install`

I get rid of blake2.h missing error, but I got many undefined reference errors e.g `(/tmp/cc9AY7g8.o:(.rodata._ZTIN8CryptoPP25MessageAuthenticationCodeE[_ZTIN8CryptoPP25MessageAuthenticationCodeE]+0x18): undefined reference to typeinfo for CryptoPP::HashTransformation)`

I was complining the example with a shell script as follow :

```
g++ -lrt -lpthread -lstdc++ -lcrypto -lcryptopp "$1" \
      "$LIBRARY_DIR/arduPiLoRa.o" \
      "$ARDUPIAPI_DIR/arduPiUART.o" \
      "$ARDUPIAPI_DIR/arduPiUtils.o" \
      "$ARDUPIAPI_DIR/arduPiMultiprotocol.o" \
      "$ARDUPI_DIR/arduPi.o" \
      "$LIBRARY_DIR/ecdh.o" \
      "$LIBRARY_DIR/aes.o" \
      -I"$ARDUPI_DIR" \
      -I"$ARDUPIAPI_DIR" \
      -I"$LIBRARY_DIR" \
      -o "$1_exe"
```

but when I compiled it directly using `g++ -o blake2 blake2.cpp -lcryptopp` the undefined reference errors disappeared, and I succesfully compiled it,

I have changed the shell script, now it finally worked, but I didn't quite undrestand it,

```
g++ -DNDEBUG -g3 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -lrt -lpthread -lstdc++ -lcrypto -lcryptopp -l:libcryptopp.a "$1" \
  "$LIBRARY_DIR/arduPiLoRa.o" \
  "$ARDUPIAPI_DIR/arduPiUART.o" \
  "$ARDUPIAPI_DIR/arduPiUtils.o" \
  "$ARDUPIAPI_DIR/arduPiMultiprotocol.o" \
  "$ARDUPI_DIR/arduPi.o" \
  "$LIBRARY_DIR/ecdh.o" \
  "$LIBRARY_DIR/aes.o" \
  -I"$ARDUPI_DIR" \
  -I"$ARDUPIAPI_DIR" \
  -I"$LIBRARY_DIR" \
  -o "$1_exe" \
  -l:libcryptopp.a
```